# Adding JPanel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a program in which a JPanel is added to a JFrame:

```
public class Test{

    Test2 test = new Test2();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Test(){

    ...
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ...

    }

    //main

    ...

    }

    public class Test2{

    JPanel test2 = new JPanel();

    Test2(){

    ...

    }

}
```

I get an error asking me to change type of 'panel' to 'component'. I do I fix this error?
It wants me to do: Component panel = new Component();

Comment: You need to post more code since what you posted should just work

Comment: JPanel is a component. Does the code you just pasted give you that error?

Comment: It sounds like you're misinterpreting the error message; what is the *exact* error message?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
public class Test{

Test2 test = new Test2();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

Test(){
...
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);
...
}

//main
...
}

//public class Test2{
public class Test2 extends JPanel {

//JPanel test2 = new JPanel();

Test2(){
...
}
```

Comment: By curiosity, is there a reason you did not extend `JFrame` directly in `Test` ? I always do this, perhaps it's a bad habit ? Upvoted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard  I'm not adding any functionality to or changing any of the existing functionality of the frame, so I just use a plain instance.  It is typically GUI builders that encourage extending frames or panels (for no good reason that I can see).

Comment: Well that make sense, Thank's for the fast answer.

Comment: After re-thinking to it, doesn't it make it easier to extends JFrame so you don't have to specify a variable each time you want to call the frame methods ? Not mentionning that extending allow you to pass parameters directly to parent constructor. Or perhaps it's just a matter of opinion, I did not find any relevant information on this in swing specifications.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard *"extending allow you to pass parameters directly to parent constructor."*  Once you do that you *are* changing the functionality of the frame.  ;)

Comment: That's true. If I understand what you tell me, needing to do any modification (such as setting the title) would re-direct you into extending the `JFrame` ?  And the reason you did not extend in that example was only because this example does not modify even one simple properties ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard *"needing to do any modification (such as setting the title) would re-direct you into extending the JFrame?"*  I'll typically pass the title in the constructor.  E.G. as in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29672939/418556).  Note also that example uses a method to configure and build the `ui` panel, again rather than extend it.  I really prefer not to extend unless doing something like custom painting.

Answer (score 4):

do it simply

```
public class Test{
    public Test(){
        design();
    }//end Test()

public void design(){
    JFame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(int w, int h);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
    f.getContentPane().add(p);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
         try{
             new Test();
         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

 }
         );
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having your Test2 class contain a JPanel, you should have it subclass JPanel:

```
public class Test2 extends JPanel {

Test2(){

...

}
```

**More details:**

[JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) is a subclass of Component, so any method that takes a Component as an argument can also take a JPanel as an argument.

Older versions didn't let you add directly to a JFrame; you had to use JFrame.getContentPane().add(Component). If you're using an older version, this might also be an issue. Newer versions of Java do let you call JFrame.add(Component) directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test2 test = new Test2();
...
frame.add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Are you sure of this? `test` is NOT a component!
To do what you're trying to do you should let `Test2` extend `JPanel` !

Answer (score 0):

Your `Test2` class is not a `Component`, it has a `Component` which is a difference.

Either you do something like

```
frame.add(test.getPanel() );
```

after you introduced a getter for the panel in your class, or you make sure your `Test2` class becomes a `Component` (e.g. by extending a `JPanel`)